# Scripting a propeller or gear ; the info window python code fails to match success of GUI duplicate and rotate applied to master gear or blade

Tags: mesh, scripting, modifiers

Given the master propeller blade or gear already drawn at the desired radius from the rotation axis, the Blender GUI approach to duplicate the original and x-rotate the copy 15-deg is to type shift+D  rx15
But the corresponding Python script which appears in the info window does not yield a copied object.
Here is the latest code suggested by StackExchange, but still not working - thanks much:

```
import bpy
from math import pi 

j = 1          # count 1-to-n blades
while j<= 3:
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move()
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value = j * 2 * pi / 4, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL')
    j=j+1
```

Comment: Make sure your object has context before running the script.  No issue for me when running script.

Comment: Thanks - Please show the code statement(s) to select the object and set context, ideally updating the preliminary code block above